# Pass JS Function Parameter into <img> Tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS function like so:

```
function onClick(images) {
        document.getElementById('imageTest').innerHTML = image syntax here
      };
```

I'm trying to pass the images parameter into the tag, like so:

```
"<img src='\data\images\" + images + "' alt='test image'";
```

but I can't get my quotes to line up correctly. What is the correct way to accomplish this?

**update:**
here is the html:

```
<body>

  <div id='map'></div>
  <div id='footer'>
    <div><img src="\data\images\otherImage.png" class="footer-img">
        <h1>Average Rent in Every US County</h1>
    </div>
    <p id='imageTest'>testing old</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What does the value of images look like that you are passing? What output are you seeing.

Comment: The output is blank and the value is: Imagenew2.png

Comment: Web paths use forward slashes not backslash and you probably want another one after directory name

Comment: What is `#imageTest`? Is it the image itself or a container?

Comment: imagetest is the container

Comment: Looks like the problem has nothing to with the quotes are you just make some typoes (mixing up ```\``` and ```/``` and forgetting a ```\``` between the name of the `images` directory and the filename. You lack a [mcve] anyway, if you had one you could just alert the string you were building to see what was wrong with it. Voting to close as off-topic for typo and lacking MCVE

Comment: Then you want to use `document.getElementById('imageTest').src= '/data/images' + images;` Notice I change the backslashes to forwardslashes, as suggested by @charlietfl

Comment: this is not a web path, it's a relative path

Answer (score -1):

This was the eventual solution:

```
x.innerHTML = '<img src="data/images/' + images + '"/>';
```