# How can I pass an image element as a JavaScript argument?

Tags: javascript, html

NO JQUERY PLEASE

So I'm trying to create a function that takes 3 arguments, the ID of a checkbox, the ID of the desired element. It checks if the specified  is checked, then changes the specified table cell to content of my choice. Here, specifically, I want the content to contain an image (`<img>`) when the checkbox is checked when the "Done" button is pressed.

```
<table style="width:75%">
            <tr>
                <th>Question</th>
                <th>Done?</th>
                <th>Are you prepared?</th>
<table style="width:75%">
    <tr>
        <th>Question</th>
        <th>Done?</th>
        <th>Are you prepared?</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Do you have a fire extinguisher in the house?</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="A" class="incline checkbox" id="aBox" value="1">
        <br>
            <span>Do you have a sturdy object to hide under?</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="B" class="incline checkbox" id="cBox" value="1">
        </td>
        <td><input name="aBoxInput" type="button" onclick="doneButton('aBox', 'uno', '<img src=/static/assets/drylands.jpeg height=125 width=125>')" class="button button2" value="Done"></input</td>
        <td><span id="uno"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried this first with just placing the specified  tag with all the styling and such inside the function, and it worked fine:

```
<td><input type="button" onclick="doneButton('aBox', 'uno') class="button button2" value="Done"></td>
            <td><span id="uno"></span></td>

function doneButton(checkboxId, changeId) {
                    var checkbox = document.getElementById(checkboxId);
                    var change = document.getElementById(changeId);
                    if (checkbox.checked) {
                        change.innerHTML = "<img src=/static/assets/drylands.jpeg height=125 width=125>') class="button button2" value="Done">";
                    }
```

Now I'm just trying to incorporate an img argument so I can call the function with whatever  I want.
I've tried a few ways to implement this, [including this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764481/pass-js-function-parameter-into-img-tag), but I might have screwed it up somewhere. Please help.

[Here is a picture of what the page looks like on the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqLrE.png)

EDIT:
If anyone wants my finished code segment, here it is (with documentation):

```
// parameters checkId1 & checkId2 are pointing to checkboxes
// targetId is the target html element
// content1 & content2 are the contents desired to replace the target element with
function doneButton(checkId1, checkId2, targetId, content1, content2) {
    var check1 = document.getElementById(checkId1);
    var check2 = document.getElementById(checkId2);
    var target = document.getElementById(targetId);
    if (check1.checked && check2.checked) {
        target.innerHTML = content1;
    }
    else {
        target.innerHTML = content2;
    }
}
/*
function doneButton can also be written as:

function doneButton(checkId1, checkId2, targetId, goodContent, badContent) {
    if (document.getElementById(checkId1).checked && document.getElementById(checkId2)) {
        document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = goodContent;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = badContent
    }

but I've chosen the un-commented one for readability
```

Comment: You said the function takes 3 arguments, but your function only has 2 arguments. What's the third argument?

Comment: There's no `value` attribute of `<img>` tags.

Comment: Passing the entire HTML of the image will be difficult because of the quotes. Maybe you could just pass the `src` URL.

Comment: Or stop using inline JavaScript and use `addEventListener()` instead.

Comment: You are not closing the `"` in `onclick` in the first code? Is it a typo?

Comment: kiner_shah...you are right...it works now...

Answer (score -1):

Ditto for most of the comments.

This works for me (assuming I understand the problem).

I made up an image display since it was not accessable to me.

The button CSS was missing as well.

```js
                // takes parameters checkbox & desired element
                // assigns checkbox & change to corresponding parameters
                // checks if checkbox is checked...
                // assigns change to a thing

 function doneButton(checkboxId, changeId, content) {
   var checkbox = document.getElementById(checkboxId);
   var change = document.getElementById(changeId);
   if (checkbox.checked) { change.innerHTML = content; }
 }

 function addImage() {
  doneButton('aBox', 'uno', '<img src="https://dummyimage.com/125x125/000/fff.jpg&text=drylands.jpg" height=125 width=125>');
 }

 function init() {
  document.getElementById('btnDone').addEventListener('click', addImage)
 }
 init();
```

```css
 button { /* missing definitions */ }
 .button2 { /* ditto */ }
```

```html
<table style="width:75%">
 <tr>
  <th>Question</th>
  <th>Done?</th>
  <th>Are you prepared?</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label>
    <span>Do you have a fire extinguisher in the house?</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" class="incline checkbox" id="aBox" value="1">
   </label>
  </td>

  <td><input type="button" class="button button2" value="Done" id='btnDone'>
  </td>
  <td><span id="uno"></span></td>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! The class="button button2" was actually referring to a Bootstrap button class. I have figured out my issue; I was simply missing an ending quote for the onlick="" button attribute.

Comment: Since you had asked to avoid JQuery, I did not think you wanted to use any other framework either.  With nested quotes and double quotes you can use `templates`, escape characters as well as performing the operation in a function as I did.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me perfectly. comment to let me know if it does not work.

```
<center> 
     <button onclick="swi('https://dogemiyagi.com/images/eth.svg')" > Pass Image</button> 
    <div id="imgDiv"></div> 
</center>
<script> 
    var pic = '';

   function swi(pic){
      let divLocation = document.getElementById("imgDiv"); 
      let imgElement = document.createElement("img"); 
      imgElement.src = pic 
      divLocation.replaceChildren(imgElement); 
  }
   
</script>
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't good answers